# How to update a storage node firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase, storage

I want the FB Storage node under the user's uid (which has only one datafile) to be updated with the new file data. Using .putData just adds another file into the node, and I'm not sure how to use the .update call as it uses metadata and I only know how to create uploadData.

```
@objc func doneTapped() {

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    let filename = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(uid)
    let storageFileRef = storageRef.child(filename)

    guard let image = self.profileImageView.image else {return}
    guard let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.3) else {return}

        storageFileRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print ("Couldn't upload new profile pic:", error as Any)
                return
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I fixed the issue, by just removing the filename. So in the previous case I was creating a uid folder and in that folder would be a list of images, but since I just want to store just one image, I made that user uid the actual filename, not the name of the folder to hold files.

```
let storageFileRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(uid)
```

Basically just shaved off the .child(filename) piece of the reference

Comment: Please accept your answer so that it shows green tick and nobody bother to read the question.